# API fetch through react js not responding

Tags: reactjs

```
//here is my js file and it showing error as //



 class TableList extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    countries: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.printful.com/countries";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ countries: data.results[0], loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.countries) {
      return <div>didn't get a countries</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.countries.name }</div>
        <div>{this.state.countries.code}</div>
        <div>{this.state.countries.states}</div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
  export default TableList;
```

//this is showing error//
 //error

```
    Access to fetch at 'https://api.printful.com/countries' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
    TableList.jsx:32 GET https://api.printful.com/countries net::ERR_FAILED
    componentDidMount @ TableList.jsx:32
    commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:22088
    commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:25340
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:337
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:386
    invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:439
    commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:25078
    unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:704
    runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12232
    commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24918
    finishSyncRender @ react-dom.development.js:24313
    performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24293
    scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23683
    updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:27101
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:27526
    unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:24421
    legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:27525
    render @ react-dom.development.js:27605
    ./src/index.js @ index.js:35
    webpack_require @ bootstrap:781
    fn @ bootstrap:149
    0 @ login.jsx:276
    webpack_require @ bootstrap:781
    checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
    webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
    (anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
    TableList.jsx:35 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: You have a CORS issue, nothing related to react or your front-end. Your API server must return proper CORS headers (there are thousands of question like this on SO)

Comment: thanku for helping